# counterpart of C#'s listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged in JS

Tags: c#, javascript, listbox

Is there such a thing as listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged but in PHP ?

Comment: Isn't there some javascript code for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, but you could use jQuery :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectList").change(function() {
        var myVal = $(this).val();
        alert(myVal);
    });
});
```

If you need to send data to server and get back from it, use $.post() / $ajax() etc ...

Comment: it doesnt seem to work `<select name="selectList">` should it make an alert with the item in the list box ?

Comment: Should do: have a look (a crap example but shows it working): http://jsfiddle.net/6gm7U/2/

Comment: You're welcome... yeah it's very handy - esp when trying out ideas without having to make a dummy page :P

Comment: first time didnt worked cuz i was using `<select name="selectList">` instead of `<select id="selectList">` :)  thanks again

Comment: No probs... And FYI, $("select[name='selectList']") would do it by the name attribute.